# how to submit a sign up form and return results within a bootstrap modal without closing it

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have really struggled submitting a form within a bootstrap modal. whenever I click the submit buttons within the body the modal closes and I have to reopen the modal to see the php results. When I connect the form with the buttons in the footer, nothing happens. How do I submit sign up forms and displaying results in the same modal without closing it. If login is successful the modal should close and redirect to another page.

Here is part of my code;

```
<!-- Login Modal -->



<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">

      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

            <img src="images/login.png" class="user">



     <?php



        if($_POST){

            if(isset($_POST['insert'])){

                 echo "The insert function is called.";

            } if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                 echo '<h2 id="errorMsg">The submit function is called.</h2>';

            }

        }



     ?>

        <form id="myForm" method="POST">

        <input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="insert">

        </form>         

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Sign up</button>

        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Login</button>-->

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When you click the submit button the form values will be send to action page.So it's impossible to display in the same modal because it will render the action page.

Comment: Look for Ajax...